# Solving an integral function with finite limits

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, integral-equations

I am trying to solve an integral equation of the form:

$$A = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y~\rho(x) \rho (y) xy,$$

where $A$ is a known constant. I am trying to find the unknown function $\rho(x)$, s.t. $\rho(x) \neq $ const. Any tips on how to approach solving this equation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are infinite functions that satisfy the equation, the constant $2 \sqrt{A}$ to begin with.

Comment: Sure, you can restrict the function to some form with some constants, compute the integral, and then solve for the constants.

Comment: I clarified the question. Thank you for pointing out this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right side factors as $$\left(\int_0^1 dx\; \rho(x) x\right)^2$$
Assuming you are working over the reals, you need $A \ge 0$, and then
$\rho(x)$ is any function such that $$ \int_0^1 dx\; \rho(x) x = \pm\sqrt{A}$$

Take any function $f$ such that $c = \int_0^1 dx\; f(x) x$ exists and is nonzero, and let
$$ \rho(x) = \pm\frac{\sqrt{A}}{c} f(x)$$
If $A \ne 0$ this gives all the solutions.